# NestJS Is it possible to access the NestApplication instance from a controller?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have these two files:

`main.ts`

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

`test-controller.ts`:

```js
@Controller('data-generator')
export class DataGeneratorController {
  //This doesn't work
  constructor(private readonly app: NestApplication) {
  }
  @Post('test')
  async test() {
    console.log(this.app)
    return 'Test injecting NestApplication';
  }
}
```

How can I access to the NestApplication within the controller? I tried to inject it in the constructor but I got this error:
`Nest can't resolve dependencies of the DataGeneratorController (?). Please make sure that the argument NestApplication at index [0] is available in the DataGeneratorModule context`

Comment: you can't. Why do you need the `app`, in first place?

Comment: We have a Test Provider that takes the Nest App as parameter and generates dummy data.  This is a part of the test provider definition: ```constructor(app: INestApplication) {
    this.app = app;
    this.dataSource = this.app.get<DataSource>(DataSource);
  }```

I implemented it already for our test suite but now I need to expose it from a controller.

Answer (score 0):

I could find a way around exporting the NestApplication instance from `main.ts` in this way:

`main.ts`:

```js
let nestApp: INestApplication;

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
  nestApp = app;
}
bootstrap();

export function getNestApp(): INestApplication {
  return nestApp;
}
```

`test-controller.ts`

```js
import { getNestApp } from '../../src/main';
@Controller('data-generator')
export class DataGeneratorController {
  
  constructor() {}
  @Post('transporter')
  async createTransporter() {
    console.log(getNestApp())
    return 'OK'
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if that is the best way though.

Comment: looks like an anti-pattern to me. But yeah, as long as `DataGeneratorController` isn't registered in the app generated by `getNestApp()`, it should work